# "Glueing" two projective lines at a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose that $X$ is a reduced projective scheme over a field $k$ (algebraically closed, say), such that it has two irreducible components, both isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$, which meet at an ordinary double point $P$ (i.e. $\widehat{\mathcal O}_{X,P} \cong k[[x,y]]/(xy)$).
Why is $X$ uniquely determined up to isomorphism?

I thought one possible strategy is to remove one smooth point on each component and show that the remainder is isomorphic to $Y := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb A^2 : xy = 0\}$ (and then glue isomorphisms).
I know this locus is affine (by EGAII, Corollary 6.7.3) but I don't know how to show it's isomorphic to $Y$.

**Added:** OK, suppose $Z = Spec(A)$ is an affine variety over $k$ with ordinary double point and two irreducible components isomorphic to $\mathbb A^1$ each. Then on coordinate rings we get surjections $A \to k[x]$, $A \to k[y]$, hence an injection $A \to k[x] \times_k k[y] \cong k[x,y]/(xy)$. *Why is this an isomorphism?*

(The assumption on the ordinary double point is clearly necessary, otherwise we could take e.g. $k[x+y,x^2] \subset k[x,y]/(xy)$, which is isomorphic to $k[s,t]/(t(s^2-t))$.)

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track here, and the next thing to do would be to use the definition of an ordinary double point. Could you add that to your post with an [edit], please?